# CKEditor Icon Paths not URLEncoded

Tags: javascript, html, css, urlencode, ckeditor4.x

I am currently using CKEditor 4 for a Desktop application and my issue is that all my icons for the toolbar do not display.  The reason for this is that when the toolbar elements are generated it finds the path to the folder with the icons and puts a style tag to set the background on each button.  One of the folders in the path contains parentheses, which results in invalid CSS (ex: `background-image: url(file///C:/ProgramFiles(x86).../icons/;`).  My question is, does anyone know where this HTML is being generated so that I can url encode it and avoid this problem?

Comment: I am using CKEditor in a desktop application, and if a user installs this application in a location with an invalid path then the editor buttons won't have icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

skin.js is the file that needs to be edited.  Line 18 is where the path for the icons is actually generated, and at this point you can add `.replace("(","%28").replace(")","%29");` to the end of the line and that will escape the parentheses.